# Cascading the Dlink DIR-601 wireless router?

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router

I'm in the basement and my computer can't receive the signal from the wireless computer on the main floor very well. On the main floor it's a dlink DIR-601 that connects to the cable modem.

I dropped an ethernet line down to the basement and tried hooking up a second DIR-601 to it (plugging the line into the WAN port on the second router).  I ran through the setup on the CD, but it's not working -- I can't get internet through the second router, neither plugged in nor wirelessly. (But I am able to connect to its wireless network, however I don't get an ip or anything, just the 169. one that means DHCP failed)

I know the line drop to the basement works, because I can get internet when I hook a laptop up to it.

Am I able to do this, or do I need a repeater, or what?

Answer (score 2):

What you need to do is turn off dhcp on your router in the basement. Make sure to assign it a local ip on your network that is above or below the dhcp range of the router upstairs. Then plug the line into a port that is not the wan port. That will give you internet access for both wireless and hard line.

Comment: Go to [this screen](http://www.support.dlink.com/emulators/dir601/100NA/lan.html) and uncheck `Enable DHCP Server`.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to get this to work. I'm running a similar config at my house with an Apple Airport being the main router, and a D-Link 300M as the slave. What's your WAN config like? If you connect to the router and enter the admin screens, under Network -> WAN the "Wan connection type" should be "Dynamic IP". Mine cannot be set to bridge mode so if you're setting yours up for dual-NAT like I have, just make sure you configure DHCP to an address range different from the one used by your main router.